# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils

Tags: java, jenkins

I am trying to run a Selenium script on a Jenkins slave machine. Because of some vulnerabilities, I cannot use Java 1.8. I installed JDK 9.0.4 on slave agent, but when trying to run the script from Jenkins, I get the following exception

Settings:
Jenkins 2.303.3
Java Version: 9.0.4

```
using settings config with name settings.xml
08:34:04 Replacing all maven server entries not found in credentials list is true
08:34:05 ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
08:34:05 java.io.IOException: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from VSXXXJENKINS16QA.FLEET.AD/XXXXXXfailed
08:34:05    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1005)
08:34:05    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1166)
08:34:05    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1155)
08:34:05    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:985)
08:34:05    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:689)
08:34:05    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
08:34:05    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
08:34:05    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
08:34:05    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
08:34:05    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:431)
08:34:05 Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils
08:34:05    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2232)
08:34:05    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
08:34:05    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3969)
08:34:05    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4829)
08:34:05    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4834)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:50)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:136)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:533)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:160)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:44)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:123)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
08:34:05    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
08:34:05    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
08:34:05    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:168)
08:34:05    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildPlexusContainer(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:166)
08:34:05    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildPlexusContainer(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:159)
08:34:05    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:110)
08:34:05    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:137)
08:34:05    at hudson.maven.MavenUtil.createEmbedder(MavenUtil.java:211)
08:34:05    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1324)
08:34:05    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1124)
08:34:05    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3338)
08:34:05    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
08:34:05    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
08:34:05    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:376)
08:34:05    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
08:34:05    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
08:34:05    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
08:34:05    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
08:34:05    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:122)
08:34:05    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
08:34:05    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from VSPWJENKINS16QA.FLEET.AD/10.1.176.32:55500
08:34:05        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1797)
08:34:05        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
08:34:05        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1001)
08:34:05        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1166)
08:34:05        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1155)
08:34:05        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:985)
08:34:05        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:689)
08:34:05        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
08:34:05        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
08:34:05        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
08:34:05        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
08:34:05        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:431)
08:34:05 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:72)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClass(BytecodeGen.java:204)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:54)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:159)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:90)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
08:34:05    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:37)
08:34:05    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3568)
08:34:05    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2350)
08:34:05    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2313)
08:34:05    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2228)
```

Comment: Which version of Guice are you using?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you should switch to Java 11 as Java 9 is not supported any more. Second, `NoClassDefFoundError` is an error that is thrown when the Java runtime tries to load the definition of a class, and that class definition is no longer available. The required class definition was present at compile time, but it is missing at runtime.

I think you have to check the class-path of target application and make sure the JAR with `com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils` is present.

**UPD**
As Luke pointed out below, exception message says "Could not initialize class...", so providing you are on Java 9 I think `com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils` uses something that belongs to `jdk.unsupported` e.g. `sun.misc.Unsafe`. In this case you should add `--add-modules` to your command line. Alternatively try a newer version of `guice`.

Comment: "NoClassDefFoundError is an error that is thrown when the Java runtime tries to load the definition of a class, and that class definition is no longer available": not always.  If the exception message says "Could not initialize class...", as it does in this question, then the class does exist and can be found, but the JVM has already tried and failed to perform static initialization on the class and so gives up doing it again.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I think you are right, I'll correct my answer

Answer (score 1):

**Using a newer version of Guice worked for me.**